# AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm tring to build an autoencoder in TensorFlow 2.0 by creating three classes: Encoder, Decoder and AutoEncoder.
Since I don't want to manually set input shapes I'm trying to infer the output shape of the decoder from the encoder's input_shape.

```
import os
import shutil

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Layer


def mse(model, original):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(model(original), original)))


def train_autoencoder(loss, model, opt, original):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        gradients = tape.gradient(
            loss(model, original), model.trainable_variables)
        gradient_variables = zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables)
        opt.apply_gradients(gradient_variables)


def log_results(model, X, max_outputs, epoch, prefix):
    loss_values = mse(model, X)

    sample_img = X[sample(range(X.shape[0]), max_outputs), :]
    original = tf.reshape(sample_img, (max_outputs, 28, 28, 1))
    encoded = tf.reshape(
        model.encode(sample_img), (sample_img.shape[0], 8, 8, 1))
    decoded = tf.reshape(
        model(tf.constant(sample_img)), (sample_img.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    tf.summary.scalar("{}_loss".format(prefix), loss_values, step=epoch + 1)
    tf.summary.image(
        "{}_original".format(prefix),
        original,
        max_outputs=max_outputs,
        step=epoch + 1)
    tf.summary.image(
        "{}_encoded".format(prefix),
        encoded,
        max_outputs=max_outputs,
        step=epoch + 1)
    tf.summary.image(
        "{}_decoded".format(prefix),
        decoded,
        max_outputs=max_outputs,
        step=epoch + 1)

    return loss_values


def preprocess_mnist(batch_size):
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    X_train = X_train / np.max(X_train)
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],
                              X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]).astype(
                                  np.float32)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train).batch(
        batch_size)

    y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)
    train_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train).batch(
        batch_size)

    X_test = X_test / np.max(X_test)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(
        X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1] * X_test.shape[2]).astype(np.float32)

    y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)

    return X_train, X_test, train_dataset, y_train, y_test, train_labels


class Encoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.output_layer = Dense(units=self.units, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, X):
        return self.output_layer(X)


class Decoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, encoder):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.output_layer = Dense(units=self.encoder.input_shape)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, X):
        return self.output_layer(X)


class AutoEncoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.encoder = Encoder(units=self.units)
        self.encoder.build(input_shape)
        self.decoder = Decoder(encoder=self.encoder)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, X):
        Z = self.encoder(X)
        return self.decoder(Z)

    @tf.function
    def encode(self, X):
        return self.encoder(X)

    @tf.function
    def decode(self, Z):
        return self.decode(Z)


def test_autoencoder(batch_size,
                     learning_rate,
                     epochs,
                     max_outputs=4,
                     seed=None):

    tf.random.set_seed(seed)

    X_train, X_test, train_dataset, _, _, _ = preprocess_mnist(
        batch_size=batch_size)

    autoencoder = AutoEncoder(units=64)
    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    log_path = 'logs/autoencoder'
    if os.path.exists(log_path):
        shutil.rmtree(log_path)

    writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_path)

    with writer.as_default():
        with tf.summary.record_if(True):
            for epoch in range(epochs):
                for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataset):
                    train_autoencoder(mse, autoencoder, opt, batch)

                # logs (train)
                train_loss = log_results(
                    model=autoencoder,
                    X=X_train,
                    max_outputs=max_outputs,
                    epoch=epoch,
                    prefix='train')

                # logs (test)
                test_loss = log_results(
                    model=autoencoder,
                    X=X_test,
                    max_outputs=max_outputs,
                    epoch=epoch,
                    prefix='test')

                writer.flush()

                template = 'Epoch {}, Train loss: {:.5f}, Test loss: {:.5f}'
                print(
                    template.format(epoch + 1, train_loss.numpy(),
                                    test_loss.numpy()))

    if not os.path.exists('saved_models'):
        os.makedirs('saved_models')
    np.savez_compressed('saved_models/encoder.npz',
                        *autoencoder.encoder.get_weights())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_autoencoder(batch_size=128, learning_rate=1e-3, epochs=20, seed=42)
```

Since the encoder's input shape is used in the build function of the decoder, I'd expect that when I train the autoencoder the encoder is built first, then the decoder, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've also tried to build the encoder in the build function of the decoder by calling `self.encoder.build()` at the start of the decoder's build function, but it didn't make any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Error I am receiving:

```
AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: I  added the complete code.

Comment: It may need to be `self.output_layer = Dense(units=input_shape[-1])`

Comment: You're probably right, but it still wouldn't solve my issue.

Comment: Yeah :) ,hopefully its a step in the right direction

Comment: @IvanLorusso I have updated your question with the error, please verify this update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there, just overcomplicated things a bit. You are receiving this error because `Decoder` layer is dependent on the `Encoder` layer **which wasn't built yet** (as the call to `build` was unsuccessful) and it's `input_shape` attribute **was not** set.

Solution would be to pass correct output shapes from `AutoEncoder` object like this:

```
class Decoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, _):
        self.output_layer = Dense(units=self.units)

    def call(self, X):
        return self.output_layer(X)


class AutoEncoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.encoder = Encoder(units=self.units)
        self.decoder = Decoder(units=input_shape[-1])
```

Notice I have removed `@tf,function` decorator as you are unlikely to get any efficiency boost (`keras` already creates the static graph under the hood for you).

Furthermore, as one can see, your build is not dependent on `input_shape` information so all the creation can be safely moved to the constructor like this:

```
class Encoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.output_layer = Dense(units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    def call(self, X):
        return self.output_layer(X)


class Decoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.output_layer = Dense(units=units)

    def call(self, X):
        return self.output_layer(X)


class AutoEncoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.encoder = Encoder(units=self.units)
        self.decoder = Decoder(units=input_shape[-1])

    def call(self, X):
        Z = self.encoder(X)
        return self.decoder(Z)

    def encode(self, X):
        return self.encoder(X)

    def decode(self, Z):
        return self.decode(Z)
```

Above begs a question whether separate `Decoder` and `Encoder` layers are really needed. IMO those should be left out, which leaves us only with this short and readable snippet:

```
class AutoEncoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.encoder = Dense(units=self.units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.decoder = Dense(units=input_shape[-1])

    def call(self, X):
        Z = self.encoder(X)
        return self.decoder(Z)

    def encode(self, X):
        return self.encoder(X)

    def decode(self, Z):
        return self.decode(Z)
```

BTW. You have an error in `sample` but that's a minor you can handle on your own no doubt.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I know I could just create the AutoEncoder (or use a sequential model), but I wanted to experiment a bit, considering it was my first attempt with TF 2.0 I wanted to complicate things a bit.

Comment: Sure, no pun intended, glad I could help.