# nyoka AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, pmml

I'm trying to output a trained Tensorflow 2.0 model to PMML using the nyoka package. When I do so, it errors out. The problem seems to be different from that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321864/attributeerror-the-layer-has-never-been-called-and-thus-has-no-defined-input-sh),
even though the error is the same, because my model does not have a complicated creation function and does, in fact, train appropriately and transform appropriately.

```py
def create_and_train(x_training,y_training,n_cols_in,modelparams):
    layers = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_cols_in,activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5)]
    for param in modelparams:
        layers.extend([tf.keras.layers.Dense(param,activation="sigmoid"),tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5)])
    layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(layers)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

    model.fit(x_training, y_training, epochs = epochs)
    with open("NN"+"_".join([str(m) for m in modelparams])+".pmml","w") as pmml_file:
        pmml = KerasToPmml(model)
        pmml.export(pmml_file)
```

Instead of a PMML file, I'm getting

```
AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Tensorflow's error. If you can print input_shape and output_shape or weights for each layer then you will be able to export it using Nyoka also.